# apt-get update starts 'by itself' and never stops running

Tags: apt, performance

I noticed my laptop becomes really slow from time to time. I think, but I'm not 100% sure, that this only happens after i plug the power in, and it started happening several days ago. Then I also noticed the disk led showing constant disk activity, and ran `iotop` to see what processes are using the disk. It showed something like:

```
apt-get -qq -y update
```

using between 98% and 99.99% of IO (all of it under `disk write`, zero under `disk read`, all the time).

I waited for several minutes to see when it will stop and it never did (when I run it, it usually takes about 20-30s to complete). Why is this happening? Can I find out what triggered `apt-get update`?

Comment: Don't you mean `apt-get -qq -y update`? It throws an error when trying to use the "y" without a "-"!

Comment: Yes, that was probably it.

Comment: I have brand spanking new debian9/stretch where I've installed a bunch of packages. It runs `apt-get -qq -y update` when booting. I didn't set that up. I'm also looking for the initiator

Comment: Found the initiator: `systemctl status apt-daily.service` - this is a real thing (appart from the missing `-` in `-y`). Upvoting and editing to fix the `-y`.

Answer (score 0):

The command updates your package list, while the modifiers -qq means "very quiet", so there is no output and -y means it automatically answers all questions with yes. Maybe you would like to change your settings for automatic search for updates which could possibly start a command like this. Maybe there is also an error with your package sources which make it run in infinite loops. Try executing the command in a terminal without the quiet-option (-qq) and see how it performs. But normally you have to use sudo to run apt-get with root privileges. Is the process you found in your question running as root or as you (normal user)?

Comment: It's running as root.

Comment: Does it do anything uncommon if you run it manually without the quiet-modifier `sudo apt-get -y update` in a terminal? Or with the -qq enabled?

Comment: I just executed the command manually, and it completed in 10-15 seconds. Thanks for helping, btw :)